# Никогда не опаздываю(,) и в этот раз не опоздаю

Tags: запятые

Можете сказать, нужна ли запятая?

• Никогда не опаздываю(,) и в этот раз не опоздаю.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*НикогдА **не опаздываю**, и в Этот раз **не опоздаю**.*

Предложения (в составе ССП) определенно-личные, действие относится к первому лицу. Здесь мыслится один **производитель** действия, но это не повод, чтобы не ставить запятую во всех ССП с определенно-личными предложениями. В заданном предложении ставится два ударения и делается пауза. Прочитать их в одну фонетическую фразу затруднительно.

Считать, что это однородные сказуемые, тоже нет оснований (в источниках такое правило не находится).

В данном случае ориентируемся на то, что простые предложения разобщены, имеют **собственные** распространители.  Также отметим **разный вид** глаголов.

**Примечание**

В грамматике эта тема названа **"Вопрос об однородных сказуемых"**
**Принцип такой**: Чем больше степень **спаянности сказуемых**, тем ближе они к однородному ряду. В противном случае предложение приближается сложному.

Односоставные предложения считаются простыми, если имеют **общий распространитель:** Т*ебя здесь любят и помнят. В вершинах деревьев тревожно прошумело, потемнело и посвежело.* Но нет информации по определенно-личным предложениям.

Comment: Я вообще никогда не вру и тебе врать не собираюсь. [Владимир Войнович. Монументальная пропаганда // «Знамя», 2000]

Comment: Это однородные сказуемые в двусоставном простом предложении (общее подлежащее).

Comment: Уберите "я" - будет то же самое.

Comment: Это вам так кажется.  А у грамматики свои законы, это точная наука. И в современной грамматике двусоставные предложения отличают от односоставных.  В любом случае, это не дискуссионный вопрос. Что касается правил пунктуации, меня тоже  интересует современный  научный подход к решению этой задачи. Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: Точные науки (англ. Exact sciences) — отрасли науки, в которых изучают количественно точные закономерности и используются строгие методы проверки гипотез, основанные на воспроизводимых экспериментах и строгих логических рассуждениях. Точные науки: математика, физика, химия, информатика... 
Точные науки, как правило, противопоставляют гуманитарным и общественным наукам, хотя и в их рамках существуют разделы и направления, методологически соответствующие подходам точных наук (например, ... корпусная лингвистика, когнитивное моделирование, статистическая социология).

Comment: У меня другое значение (оценочное).  Гуманитарная наука тоже наука (система знаний), а не обычные суждения кого-либо. Впрочем, я не настаиваю на своем понимании  грамматики как точной науки (в этом смысле), некоторые наши участники ориентируются на «свою грамматику». (В этом противопоставление: современные учебники по грамматике и своя грамматика.) Но это не тема данного вопроса.  СПАСИБО за внимание.
 ТОЧНЫЙ, 2. Полностью соответствующий какому-л. образцу или чему-л. заданному, установленному, требуемому. 3. Конкретный и определённый, предельно полный и верный, не приблизительный, не общий.

Comment: Да и вопрос об однородных сказуемых является дискуссионным.